# discriminant as a product of pairwise differences of roots

Tags: polynomials, discriminant

It is known that the discriminant of a polynomial $f \in K[x]$ can be described as a function of its coefficients via polynomial resultants. But in the explicit formulation of the determinant $\Delta$, namely as a product of the differences of the polynomial's roots $r_i$
$$ \Delta = \prod_{i<j} (r_i - r_j)^2 $$
Is there a way to see that $\Delta \in K$?

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta$ is [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) with respect to any permutation of the roots $r_i$ (this is why we square the pairwise differencies: otherwise, $\Delta$ could change its sign after permuting the roots). Thus, [it can be expressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) as a polynomial of the elementary symmetric polynomials of $r_i$, [which are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) precisely the coefficients of $f$.